# Apache Spark DataFrame, CSV and raw line value

Tags: apache-spark

I can read csv file with Apache Spark in the following way, for example:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("csvfile.csv")
```

I there any way to access the whole original(raw) line(from which csv DataFrame row was constructed) as a single String value and put it into new DataFrame column?

Comment: Can you just read it as a text file instead: `df = spark.read.text("csvfile.csv")`

Comment: Do you need a DF with **just** the single row as String in a Column, or a DF with all Columns from `csvfile.csv` **plus** the original raw String in a Column?

Comment: @pheeleeppoo all Columns plus original raw String in the Column

Comment: @TravisHegner I want to keep CSV benefits while reading file as CSV and add one additional column to the result DataFrame with original raw String.